# The code renders the graph correctly locally but shows an empty space when deployed. What could be causing this issue?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, mern, apexcharts

When deploying my React code that renders a graph locally without issues, it instead displays an empty space when deployed. The graph is generated using ReactApexCharts and relies on data fetched from an API. The deployment environment seems to differ in rendering the graph compared to my local setup. I've verified the data fetching and rendering logic, ensuring all dependencies are correctly installed. Any insights into what might cause this disparity between local and deployed rendering would be greatly appreciated.

```
const KnowledgeDomainMainPage = ({ KDData }) => {
  const [categories2, setCategories2] = useState([]);
  const [overAllObtainedMarks, setOvearllObtainedMarks] = useState([]);
  const [overallTotalScore, setOverallTotalScore] = useState([]);
  const [totalPercentageArray, setTotalPercentage] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const categoriesArray = KDData?.knowledgeDomains.map((KD) => {
      return KD.domain;
    });
    setCategories2(categoriesArray);

    const obtainedArray = KDData?.knowledgeDomains.map((KD) => {
      return KD.subjectScores.reduce(
        (acc, curr) => acc + curr.obtainedScore,
        0
      );
    });
    setOvearllObtainedMarks(obtainedArray);

    const totalArray = KDData?.knowledgeDomains.map((KD) => {
      return KD.subjectScores.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.totalScore, 0);
    });
    setOverallTotalScore(totalArray);

    const percentageArray = overallTotalScore?.map((KD, index) => {
      return KD === 0
        ? 0
        : Math.round((overAllObtainedMarks[index] / KD) * 100);
    });
    setTotalPercentage(percentageArray);
  }, [KDData]);
  console.log(totalPercentageArray);

  const optionsBar = {
    chart: {
      type: "bar",
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: true,
        borderRadius: 8,
        barHeight: "14px",
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    grid: {
      yaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: categories2,
      max: 100,
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      enabledOnSeries: undefined,
      formatter: function (value, { seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
        return value !== 0
          ? categories2[dataPointIndex] + ": " + value + "(%)"
          : "";
      },
      textAnchor: "middle",
      distributed: false,
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: -12,
      style: {
        fontSize: "12px",
        fontFamily: "Poppins, sans-serif",
        colors: ["#474B4E"],
      },
    },
    colors: ["#003354"],
  };

  const seriesBar = [
    {
      name: "Series 1",
      data: totalPercentageArray ? totalPercentageArray : [10, 20, 30, 40],
    },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      {totalPercentageArray && totalPercentageArray.length > 0 && (
        <div className={styles.bar_chart}>
          <ReactApexChart
            style={{ marginTop: "40px" }}
            options={optionsBar}
            series={seriesBar}
            type="bar"
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Gqf.png)] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/85CaW.png)

These are images of console from deployed and local.